# projection matrix clarification

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to understand projection into subspaces following these set of [notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/projections-onto-subspaces/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.2sum.pdf)

There, we got that if we wanted to project a vector $b$ into subspace spanned by vectors ${v_1,...,v_k}$, we form the matrix $A=[v_1,...,v_k]$ where the columns of $A$ are the vectors $v_i$. Then we do $A(A^{\top}A)^{-1}A^{\top}b$. But I don't get why $(A^{\top}A)^{-1}$ exists at all.

Comment: It doesn’t unless the vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: when the vector are linearly independent,  how do you then show  invertible?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{V} = span(v_1,v_2,..,v_n)$. Let $M= A(A'A)^{-1}A'$.

A projection $P$ should be able to do the following: If $v \in \mathbf{V}$, then $Pv= v$. If $v\in \mathbf{V^{\bot}}$, then $Pv = 0$.

We'll verify that $M$ will do what a projection matrix will do.

1. If $v \in \mathbf{V}$, then $v = Ax$ for some $x$ (why ?).

   So,   $Mv = A(A'A)^{-1}A'v = A(A'A)^{-1}A'Ax = Ax = v$.
2. If $v\in \mathbf{V^{\bot}}$, then $A'v = \begin{bmatrix}
          v_{1}^{'} \\
          v_{2}^{'} \\
          \vdots \\
          v_{n}^{'}
        \end{bmatrix} . v =\begin{bmatrix}
          v_{1}^{'}.v \\
          v_{2}^{'}.v \\
          \vdots \\
          v_{n}^{'}.v
        \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
          0 \\
          0 \\
          \vdots \\
          0
        \end{bmatrix}$.

   Note: If $v\in \mathbf{V^{\bot}}$, then $v$ is perpendicular to $v_1$, $v_2$,..,$v_n$. Hence,  $\  \ v_1^{'}v =v_2^{'}v= \dots=v_n^{'}v = 0 $.

Hence $M$ is a projection matrix and to prove 1, we need $(A'A)^{-1}$ in $M$. English is not my primary language, so please ignore if there are any grammatical mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the comments that the real issue here is to show that $A^\top A$ is invertible given that $A$ has linearly independet columns. To see this, consider the product

$$A^\top A = \begin{bmatrix} 
A^\top v_1 & \cdots & A^\top v_k \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, we can easily see that the columns if this matrix is linearly independent as well (see below). Also, if the $v_j$-s are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $A^\top$ is $k \times n$ and $A$ is $n \times k$, so $A^\top A$ is $k \times k$. Hence, the columns of $A^\top A$ form a linearly independent set of $k$ vector in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and it is invertible.

At last, why is $\{ A^\top v_1, \ldots, A^\top v_k \}$ a linearly independent set? Consider the equation

$$\sum_{j=1}^k c_j (A^\top v_j) = \mathbf{0} \iff A^\top \big( \sum_{j=1}^k c_j v_j \big) = \mathbf{0}$$

Since $A^\top$ has linearly independent columns, this equation has only the trivial solution

$$\sum_{j=1}^k c_j v_j = \mathbf{0}, $$

which again means that $c_1 = \cdots = c_k=0$ since $\{ v_1, \ldots, v_k \}$ is a linearly independent set.

Answer (score 1):

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}, k \le n$ and hence $A^T \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ and $A^TA \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$.

The question is why is it that $A^TA$ is non-singular if columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

- If you have learned about SVD decomposition, write $A=UDV^T$ where $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}, V \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ of which they are column orthogonal and $D \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ is a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries. We have $A^TA = UD^2U^T$, we can clearly see that the rank of the matrix remains to be $k$  and hence it is invertible.
- Suppose $v \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $A^TAv=0$, if we can show that $v=0$, then we have shown that $A^TA$ is invertible. We have $v^TA^TAv=0$, which is $\|Av\|^2=0$. That is we have $Av=0$. Now, using the information that columns of $A$ are linearly independent, we conclude that the system $Av=0$ can only have the trivial solution, that is $v=0$. Hence $A^TA$ is invertible.